# failed to parse field [duration] of type [long] in document

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, elk, jaeger

In a kuberenetes cluster, when pushing the data of jaeger-tracing to elasticsearch i am getting the below error in the jaeger-tracing-collector, I do not have any filter like logstash/filebeat in between. The jaeger data is direclty pushed into elasticsearch. I am very new to elasticsearch and related things, any help would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance...

Error :

```
{
  "level": "error",
  "ts": 1656982524.1294773,
  "caller": "config/config.go:137",
  "msg": "Elasticsearch part of bulk request failed",
  "map-key": "index",
  "response": {
    "_index": "jaeger-span-2022-07-05",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "9EHay4EBv4T2qdA80Ei7",
    "status": 400,
    "error": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "failed to parse field [duration] of type [long] in document with id '9EHay4EBv4T2qdA80Ei7'. Preview of field's value: '18446744073709550616'",
      "caused_by": {
        "reason": "Numeric value (18446744073709550616) out of range of long (-9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807)n at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 199]",
        "type": "i_o_exception"
      }
    }
  },
  "stacktrace": "github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/pkg/es/config.(*Configuration).NewClient.func2\\n\\tgithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/pkg/es/config/config.go:137\\ngithub.com/olivere/elastic.(*bulkWorker).commit\\n\\tgithub.com/olivere/elastic@v6.2.27+incompatible/bulk_processor.go:588\\ngithub.com/olivere/elastic.(*bulkWorker).work\\ntgithub.com/olivere/elastic@v6.2.27+incompatible/bulk_processor.go:501"
}
```

Jaeger version : 1.21.0
Elasticsearch version : 7.17.5

Comment: Can you add the result you get from calling `GET jaeger-span-2022-07-05`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

It seems you are out of bound as per the error message

> "reason": "Numeric value (18446744073709550616) out of range of long (-9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807)n at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 199]"

## Solution

As [@Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val) mentioned in the comment, having your mapping would help.

First of all to store the value `18446744073709550616` you need to choose either[from this list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html):

- float
- double
- unsigned_long

Then when creating your index, you set the type for the field:

```json
PUT 74388060/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "big_number": {
        "type": "float"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then

```json
POST /74388060/_doc/
{
  "big_number": "18446744073709550616"
}
```

And you should be out of the woods.

Comment: right @paulo but how do i change the data type?

Comment: Thanks @paulo i was able resolve the exception